# Div positioning within a webpage

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

Edit:

Current layout:

[image]

Im trying to work out how within my ASP webpage design I can posistion a div (server side) under another div.

To my question further I'll use the following screenshots:

Currently this is my layout:

[image]

I want to position 2 more div one under another to give me a 'title' div and a 'description' div tat will later be populated by my database results, as shown:

[image]

This is my current source code. Can someone push me in the right direction of how i go about implementing these divs one of top of another like this?

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeBehind="Show.aspx.cs" Inherits="ViewCDs.Show" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

     <div style=" float:left;">
     <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Height="145px" ViewStateMode="Enabled" 
     Width="185px" />

      </div>
      <div style=" float:left; width: 395px; height: 140px;">

      <asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server">
       <EditItemTemplate>
           coffeeName:
           <asp:TextBox ID="coffeeNameTextBox" runat="server" 
               Text='<%# Bind("coffeeName") %>' />
           <br />
           coffeeOrigin:
           <asp:TextBox ID="coffeeOriginTextBox" runat="server" 
               Text='<%# Bind("coffeeOrigin") %>' />
           <br />
           coffeeStrength:
           <asp:TextBox ID="coffeeStrengthTextBox" runat="server" 
               Text='<%# Bind("coffeeStrength") %>' />
           <br />
           coffeeGrind:
           <asp:TextBox ID="coffeeGrindTextBox" runat="server" 
               Text='<%# Bind("coffeeGrind") %>' />
           <br />
           coffeePrice:
           <asp:TextBox ID="coffeePriceTextBox" runat="server" 
               Text='<%# Bind("coffeePrice") %>' />
           <br />
           coffeeQty:
           <asp:TextBox ID="coffeeQtyTextBox" runat="server" 
               Text='<%# Bind("coffeeQty") %>' />
           <br />
           coffeeRRP:
           <asp:TextBox ID="coffeeRRPTextBox" runat="server" 
               Text='<%# Bind("coffeeRRP") %>' />
           <br />
           <asp:LinkButton ID="UpdateButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" 
               CommandName="Update" Text="Update" />
           &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="UpdateCancelButton" runat="server" 
               CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
          </EditItemTemplate>
          <InsertItemTemplate>
           coffeeName:
           <asp:TextBox ID="coffeeNameTextBox" runat="server" 
               Text='<%# Bind("coffeeName") %>' />
           <br />
           coffeeOrigin:
           <asp:TextBox ID="coffeeOriginTextBox" runat="server" 
               Text='<%# Bind("coffeeOrigin") %>' />
           <br />
           coffeeStrength:
           <asp:TextBox ID="coffeeStrengthTextBox" runat="server" 
               Text='<%# Bind("coffeeStrength") %>' />
           <br />
           coffeeGrind:
           <asp:TextBox ID="coffeeGrindTextBox" runat="server" 
               Text='<%# Bind("coffeeGrind") %>' />
           <br />
           coffeePrice:
           <asp:TextBox ID="coffeePriceTextBox" runat="server" 
               Text='<%# Bind("coffeePrice") %>' />
           <br />
           coffeeQty:
           <asp:TextBox ID="coffeeQtyTextBox" runat="server" 
               Text='<%# Bind("coffeeQty") %>' />
           <br />
           coffeeRRP:
           <asp:TextBox ID="coffeeRRPTextBox" runat="server" 
               Text='<%# Bind("coffeeRRP") %>' />
           <br />
           <asp:LinkButton ID="InsertButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" 
               CommandName="Insert" Text="Insert" />
           &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="InsertCancelButton" runat="server" 
               CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
           </InsertItemTemplate>
           <ItemTemplate>

           <b>Origin:</b>
           <asp:Label ID="coffeeOriginLabel" runat="server" 
               Text='<%# Bind("coffeeOrigin") %>' />
           <br />
           <br />
           <b>Grind:</b>
           <asp:Label ID="coffeeGrindLabel" runat="server" 
               Text='<%# Bind("coffeeGrind") %>' />
           <br />
           <br />
           <b>Price: £</b>
           <asp:Label ID="coffeePriceLabel" runat="server" 
               Text='<%# Bind("coffeePrice") %>' />
           <br />
           <br />
               <b>Strength:</b>
           <asp:Label ID="coffeeStrengthLabel" runat="server" 
               Text='<%# Bind("coffeeStrength") %>' />
           <br />
           <br />
           <b>Stock Level:</b>
           <asp:Label ID="coffeeQtyLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("coffeeQty") %>' />
           <br />


 </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:FormView>
 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
       ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:CoffeeConnectionString %>" 
       SelectCommand="SELECT [coffeeName], [coffeeOrigin], [coffeeStrength], [coffeeGrind], [coffeePrice], [coffeeQty], [coffeeRRP] FROM [Coffees]">
</asp:SqlDataSource>

<br />
</div>

<div style=" float:left; width: 339px; height: 140px;">
<br />

<div style=" float:left; width: 165px; height: 25px;">

    <b><asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Select Coffee Grind:"></asp:Label>  </b>
</div>

<div style=" float:right; width: 165px; height: 25px;">
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" Height="21px" Width="161px">
    <asp:ListItem>Beans</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Smooth</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Course</asp:ListItem>
 </asp:DropDownList>
 </div>

  <div style=" float:left; width: 165px; height: 40px;">
  <br />
      <b><asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Quantity:"></asp:Label></b>
 </div>

  <div style=" float:right; width: 165px; height: 40px;">
  <br />

      <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Width="40px">1</asp:TextBox>

  </div>

  <div style=" float:left; width: 165px; height: 40px;">
  <br />

      <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Buy" />

 </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would simply need to add two more divs beneath that code.

```
<div id="title"> </div> <br/>
<div id="description"> </div> <br/>
```

However if you would like to control their attributes such as visibility then you would just need to make those asp.net panels.

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="title"> </asp:Panel> <br/>
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="description"> </asp:Panel> <br/>
```

Comment: many thanks. Feel a little silly asking it. I have put the div in and they do appear. I now have another issue (I have edited my question with a new screenshot to reflect this) where my FormView is masking my 'title' div. Also i cant seem to put the title div under this even with a <br />

Comment: This is because your divs are floating.  You first need to place a <div style="clear:both"></div> under your FormView to clear your floats.  Then you can adjust your margin of your title div such as <div id="title" style="margin-top:20px"></div>.  If this works would appreciate a vote up:)

Comment: Managed to get them positioned myself a little while ago but your div placement was 100% correct many thanks! Upvote given